# Not receiving expected output from code in C++

Tags: c++

My program starts by displaying the contents of this file:

```
Key     Title                   Price

1       Super_Mario_Bros        $20
2       Mega_Man                $25
3       Kirby's_Adventure       $30
4       Castlevania             $35
```

It then prompts the user allows to select the number of games that they want and then to select each game based on the key. After that, it should then set the value of the variable `title` according the key that was chosen and print out the selected game(s).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int invoice(int *game);

int main() {

//Displays list of games with their prices, prompts user to select one, and sets it as the value       of the game variable.
int number;
int c;

std::ifstream g("games");
if (g.is_open())
std::cout << g.rdbuf();

cout << "How many games would you like to order (Enter a number between 1 and 5): " << endl;
cin >> number;

int game[number];

while (true) {

for (c = 0; c <= number; c++) {
cout <<endl<< "Select a game (Enter the key): " << endl;
cin >> game[number];
}

bool result = invoice(game);


for (c = 0; c <= number; c++) {
string title;
int price;

cout <<endl<< "Your order contains the game: " << title << endl;

}

return 0;

}
}
int invoice(int *game) {

string title;
int number;
int c;

for (c = 0; c < number; c++) {

int g = game[c];
string title;
int price;
if (g == 1) {
title = "Super_Mario_Bros";
}
else if (g == 2) {
title = "Mega_Man";
}
else if (g == 3) {
title = "Kirbys_Adventure";
}
else if (g == 4) {
//price = 35;
title = "Castlevania";


g++;
}
}


if (game[c] == 0 || game[c] == 1 || game[c] == 2 || game[c] == 3) {
return true; }

return 0;

}
```

The output that I get is this:

```
How many games would you like to order (Enter a number between 1 and 5):
2

Select a game (Enter the key):
1

Select a game (Enter the key):
2

Select a game (Enter the key):
3

Your order contains the game:

Your order contains the game:

Your order contains the game:
```

I am expecting this output with `Your order contains the game:` depending on what is chosen:

```
Your order contains the game: Kirbys_Adventure

Your order contains the game: Castlevania

Your order contains the game: Super_Mario_Bros
```

What seems to be happening is that the `title` variable isn't being set based on the selection. I've tried altering the code in the function but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the while(true) and just keep the for loop inside, it will terminate when c < number anyways...

Comment: Please format your code so there is indentation. Additionally, please shorten the code to the areas which are causing the problem, and any relevant information, not the whole program.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are not setting your 'title' variable before you display it.
Perhaps your invoice method could adjust the value of title each iteration of the loop

This void function will just update title's value to the relevant game name:

```
void invoice(int gameNum, string &title) {

string games[4] = {"Super_Mario_Bros", "Mega_Man", "Kirbys_Adventure", 
"Castlevania"};

title = games[gameNum];

}
```

This will allow you to update your title variable by calling the invoice() method.

e.g

```
string title;

for (c = 0; c < number; c++) 
{
     invoice(game[c], title);

     cout << endl << "Your order contains the game: " << title << endl;
}
```